# Multi Tenancy Databases with Symfony2 and Doctrine: How to separate Tenant Data?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

We are building a multi-tenancy application where all tenants data is stored in the same database/tables. Every table has a column "tenant_id" which identifies the tenant.

How can I achieve this goal using Symfony2 and Doctrine?

For Symfony 1, there was a plugin called [sfMultiTenantPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMultiTenantPlugin) but it seems not to exist in Symfony2. The Plugin added the tenant_id dynamically to all queries to the database.

What is the best practice to use Doctrine ORM with the described data structure?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does no one have an answer or do you need more information?

Comment: We'r working on the same thing, and having similar issues, I found this bundle and i'v yet to try it out 
https://github.com/SyndicateTheory/SyndMultiTenantBundle
not sure if for Symfony1 or 2... If u have any more information, please update this question, thanks.

Comment: @ulilicht did you find the solution ?

Comment: That bundle link is not working any more